# MathJax doesn't render dynamically... Why not?

Tags: support, mathjax

When I post this:

\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n}{k}x^n=\frac{x^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}}\tag{1}

... all I see is string of code, not the nifty looking math symbols.

When I post the above to a test site, however, it renders just fine. And I can see all of the math just fine on the math.stackexchange forum.

The only problem is when I'm inputting the question. I don't know what the above will look like when I post it.

Is there something I can do to correct this?

Thanks.

Comment: Now that the question has posted, it still looks like gobbledeegook to me.

Comment: You need to learn to compile code in your head.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add some `$` to the code.

Comment: Perfect! I tried it and it worked! Thanks so much. I'm glad it was a simple solution. I added the symbol to the front and back: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n}{k}x^n=\frac{x^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}}\tag{1}$

Comment: That's the most capitalistic solution possible. Something doesn't work? Throw a bunch of $'s onto it, and it works!

Comment: In this case it only took two $'s.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche four, it is displayed. :D